# How to repair a broken BIOS Setup Utility

Tags: linux, bios

I installed a Linux OS (Solus Mate) on a new Acer Swift 1 SF114-32.
It came with Windows 10 S preinstalled, which I removed in the process.

Since then my BIOS Setup Utility (InsydeH20 Setup Utility) seems broken, only allowing me to access the "Exit" options (see attached photos).

Loading setup defaults (& saving) seems to have no effect.

In addition, I don't seem able to boot from a USB Drive, as it default boots from internal memory and the F12 Boot device menu does not show USB drives any longer. Not sure, if that is due to secure boot being enabled.

Booting the OS works as expected however Acer only provides BIOS update tools for windows for this laptop.

If anybody knows how to repair the BIOS Setup Utility or with what alternative to replace it I'd like their help.
Thank you in advance!

[BIOS Setup Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yxKZ.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Most settings in a uefi bios are on a separate EFI partition, maybe it got deleted?

Comment: Bit of an ugly hack but I wonder if a windows2go or temporary windows install in trial mode would work here. You did make a backup of the default install, right?

Comment: You might be able to download and reinstall BIOS: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/144526/how-to-flash-a-bios-when-only-a-windows-binary-is-provided Make a disk image first, though.

Comment: @Moab good idea. I do have a fat32 partition (488MiB) flagged as 'boot, esp'. In contrast to my other systems, it is not flagged as 'efi' nor does it have a Mount Point set. -- What would happen if I were to delete the partition? My OS would become unbootable, but would USB drives boot again?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Since it is comes eMMC storage, which to my knowledge I can't remove from the laptop, I'm afraid I can't create an image of the current contents nor put an image on it. In my understanding that would be necessary for what you propose (may be wrong though). I may be able to put in an m.2 ssd with something preinstalled. Any chances that would be a viable option?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I would need a external drive for that though, wouldn't I? Since I can't boot from those, that might be a problem. I could try to add an ssd to it (to my knowledge it has an extra m.2 slot) with free dos installed, would you recommend that?

Comment: Have you tried another function key, e.g. F9, which might allow selecting boot drive without entering BIOS?

Comment: This tutorial might help you flash your BIOS on Linux: https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/flash-your-lenovo-ideapad-laptop-bios-from-linux-using-uefi-capsule-updates-a82e455ea29c

Answer (score 2):

1.- Download some Win10 PE iso file

2.- Write it on a USB key (preferably a model that has an activity led)

3.- Turn on your Acer Swift while your press Fn+ESC

4.- You should see your USB led blinking

5.- On Windows download the latest Acer Swift BIOS, v1.11

6.- Unzip it

7.- Unpack the BIOS_111.exe file with P7zip to obtain these files: Ding.wav, FlsHook.exe, H2OFFT64.sys, H2OFFT.inf, HashTool.efi, mfc90u.dll,                   Microsoft.VC90.MFC.manifest, msvcr90.dll, PreLoader.efi, BiosImageProcx64.dll, error.log, FWUpdLcl.exe, H2OFFT.cat, H2OFFT-Wx64.exe  isflash.bin, Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest, msvcp90.dll, platform.ini

8.- Run H2OFFT-Wx64.exe

If you want to ovewrite the same BIOS version, edit the platform.ini file and change in the section: [Bios_Version_Check]
Flag=1 to Flag=0